# Young adult Novel with Lavender Blue as recurring theme

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

I am looking for Young adult novel which:

1. is very reminiscent of a Keatley Snider novel
2. Involves a young girl, a hedge maze and the song Lavender Blue being
   repeated throughout.

I think there was a girl similar to her in looks but who was trying to destroy her? I have been searching for this for years.

Comment: When did you read this? Where? Paperback or hardback? You can find a list of questions to answer at http://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info

Comment: And is this the song you're referring to? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lavender's_Blue

Comment: It looks like you've created more than one account or at least I'm assuming [this is also you](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/78800/bhansai). You can find info on how to merge your accounts at http://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts

Answer (score 7):

*[Lavender-Green Magic](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1233097.Lavender_Green_Magic?from_search=true)* by Andre Norton perhaps?

[image: Book cover]

> A mysterious maze
>
> Eleven-year-old Holly Wade and her twin siblings, Judy and Crockett, are sent to live with their grandparents in the small town of Dimsdale, Massachusetts when their father is declared missing in action in Vietnam. Dimsdale is nothing like Boston; there are only two other African-American children in the entire school. Even worse, Grandpa and Grandma Wade live in an old junkyard! While exploring one day, Holly, Judy, and Crockett wander into an overgrown hedge maze--and find themselves transported back in time to Dimsdale's past. Can they right an ancient wrong and free the town of Dimsdale from a witch's curse?

It has the hedge maze, and one of the reviews comments that "the 'witches' Hagar and Tamar are not 'sisters', but different aspects of the same character", which fits your idea of similar-looking characters trying to destroy each other. Lastly, the book does [twice quote](https://books.google.com/books?id=EsU2_-geCqMC&q=lavender%27s%20blue#v=snippet&q=lavender%27s%20blue&f=false) the old folk tune, "[Lavender's Blue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lavender%27s_Blue)".

This is the [fifth book in a series](https://www.goodreads.com/series/58163-the-magic-books), but my impression is that they're loosely connected, at best, and the covers certainly don't call attention to it.

Comment: If this is the answer, don't forget to click on the check-mark by the voting buttons to accept it.